# I am trying to take fft and dtft of a grey scale image from first principals(so without using built it fft or dtft functions) using python

Tags: python, fft

I need to write a function that computes the fft and another to compute the dft of a a composite sinusoidal signal and to then plot the phase and magnitude spectrum there of. I then need to use the same functions to compute the fft and dft of a greyscale image. I have the functions and can get the transforms of a composite sine wave but I am not sure how to apply this to an image. I believe that the pixels in an image are stored as a 2D array where as the sine function is only 1D

here is my code:

```
import numpy as ny 
import matplotlib.pyplot as mplot 
import time as tm # used to claculate time taken to perform functions 

# Variables
sample_rate = 0
sample_period = 0
time = 0 # Total time
T = 0
n = 0
freq = 0
y = 0 # Used to build signal to apply the DTF to
Y = 0 # Signal after the DTF
#***

# Main
sample_rate = 128
sample_period = 1/sample_rate
time = ny.arange(0,2,sample_period) # Sample set up to got from 0 - 2 seconds

# Signal 1
freq = 1
y = ny.sin(2*ny.pi*freq*time)
# Signal 2
freq = 3
y += 2*ny.sin(2*ny.pi*freq*time)
# Signal 3
freq = 5
y += 3*ny.sin(2*ny.pi*freq*time)
# Signal 4
freq = 7
y += 0.5*ny.sin(2*ny.pi*freq*time)

#time domain plot of signal
mplot.figure(figsize = (6,4))
mplot.plot(time, y, 'b')
mplot.title('Plot of signal y')
mplot.xlabel('Time (s)')
mplot.ylabel('Amplitude')
#mplot.show()
#***

# Functions
# Discrete Fourier Transform
def DFT(y):
    n = ny.arange(len(y))
    k = n.reshape((len(y), 1))
    e = ny.exp(-2j * ny.pi * k * n / len(y))
    
    Y = ny.dot(e,y)
    
    return Y

# Fast Fourier Transform
def FFT(y):

    length = len(y)
    if length == 1:
        return y
    else:
        even = FFT(y[::2])
        odd = FFT(y[1::2])
        fact = ny.exp(-2j * ny.pi * ny.arange(length) / length)
        
        Y = ny.concatenate(( even + odd*fact[:int(length/2)] , even + odd*fact[int(length/2):] )) # Joining the arrays together
        return Y

#***
#get DFT of composite signal
dftstart = tm.time()
Y = DFT(y)
dftend = tm.time()
dfttime = dftend - dftstart
# calculate the frequency
n = ny.arange(len(Y))
T = len(Y)/sample_rate
freq = n/T 

#plot magnitude spctrum of DTFT of composite signal 
mplot.figure(figsize = (6,4))
mplot.stem(freq, abs(Y), 'r')
mplot.title('Discrete Fourier Transform of signal y')
mplot.xlabel('Frequency (Hz)')
mplot.ylabel('DFT Amplitude |Y(e^jw)|')
#mplot.show()

#plot phase response of DFT
mplot.figure(figsize = (6,4))
mplot.plot(freq, Y/abs(Y), 'r')
mplot.title('phase spectrum of DFT of signal y')
mplot.xlabel('Frequency (Hz)')
mplot.ylabel('Phase(rad/s)')


#get fft of composite signal
fftstart = tm.time()
Y = FFT(y)
fftend = tm.time()
ffttime = fftend - fftstart
# calculate the frequency
length = len(Y)
n = ny.arange(length)
T = len(Y)/sample_rate
freq = n/T 

#plot magnitude spectrum of fft of composite signal 
mplot.figure(figsize = (6,4))
mplot.stem(freq, abs(Y), 'r')
mplot.title('Fast Fourier Transform of signal y')
mplot.xlabel('Frequency (Hz)')
mplot.ylabel('FFT Amplitude |X(e^jw)|')
#mplot.show()

#plot phase response of fft
mplot.figure(figsize = (6,4))
mplot.plot(freq, Y/abs(Y), 'b')
mplot.title('phase response of FFT of signal y')
mplot.xlabel('Frequency (Hz)')
mplot.ylabel('Phase(rad/s)')
mplot.show()

print("time to execute dft: " + str(dfttime))
print("time to execute fft: " + str(ffttime))
```

If someone could advise me on how to apply this to a greyscale image it would be greatly appreciated

Comment: There is a difference between the DTFT and the DFT. You are computing the DFT. And the FFT also computes the DFT. You are using two different algorithms to compute the same thing. The DTFT uses an infinite discrete input signal, and produces a continuous output. There’s obviously no algorithm to compute that from data…

Comment: A 2D DFT is computed by applying the 1D DFT to each row of the matrix, then go each column of the result.